# Almost everywhere equality of tensor of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ be Lebesgue measurable and $f_1(x)g_1(y) = f_2(x)g_2(y)$ for a.e. $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$.
Then, is it true that $f_1(x)g_1(x) = f_2(x)g_2(x)$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ?

Motivation for this problem.
Of course, we can easily find a lot of measurable functions $F, G:\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $F=G$ a.e. and $F(x,x) \neq G(x, x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Therefore, "$F(x,y)=G(x,y)$ for a.e.$(x,y)$ $\Rightarrow$ $F(x, x) = G(x,x)$ for a.e. $x$" is false. However, it is not clear for me that this is also false even if $F$ and $G$ are tensors.

Background of this problem.
For a function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$, $x \mapsto F(x,x)$ is sometimes important. For example, if $k \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d)$ and if $T \in B(L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d))$ is a bounded operator whose integral kernel is $k$, then $k(x,x)$ is the "density" of $T$, which is physically important.

Comment: It looks like you made a typo in the conclusion part.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: I see no reason to close this question.  Of course it has a very short statement but that is because it is concise and straight to the point rather than a demerit.